# What is the difference between magnetic field formula with current and the one for infinite wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

As stated, aren't the two formula indicating the same things as current is essentially what is in a wire?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations are generally different. The equation on the left is the magnetic field generated by a charged particle moving at constant velocity (under the assumption the velocity is much smaller than the speed of light). The equation on the right is the magnitude of the magnetic field generated outside an infinite wire carrying a uniform current.

However, you may choose to model the uniform current in an infinite wire as many charged particles moving at constant velocity. The field generated by each particle in the current is given by the left equation, and superposing the fields properly, you could recover the right equation! In this sense, the left equation is much more general than the right. As long as we properly construct a current distribution from charges at constant velocity, the left equation (with the principle of superposition) allows us to calculate the magnetic field from all sorts of non-uniform currents.